# Mod rewrite catch get query and add another query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When user enters

http://www.test.com/inbox.php?msg_op=inbox

I must catch the GET, and make it like

http://www.test.com/inbox.php?msg_op=inbox&lang=en

What I have tried is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .

RewriteRule ^inbox.php?(.*) inbox.php?$1&lang=en [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work. I only get LANG value in $_GET. How can I do that?

Comment: @anubhava sorry my mistake. corrected it. it is lang=en

Comment: ok below answer should work then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this simplified rule with a negated condition and `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)lang=en(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^inbox\.php$ $0?lang=en [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks very much. can you explain me so I understand it better, why I should use QSA, what does the first line means?

Comment: `QSA` is query string append to add new parameter in existing query string. And condition is to check of you already have `lang=en` in query string or not.